# How to check eloquent relationship between two tables?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables, customers and users in **users table** I have:

id

name

email

password

**in customers I have**

id

customer_id

package_id

when someone register, in user table create id number and in the same time it creates in customers table: id and **customer_id** get the same value from id->user 
inside customers model I have

```
 public function owners()
 {
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'customers');
}
```

all I need now just to check after registration if package_id for the current customer_id is empty or null return to.. else if it has any number return to...
I tried this in **controller** but doesn't work

```
public function redirectpackage(Request $request)
{
if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->customer->package_id == 1) {
return view('index.customer.customerpackage'); 
 }
 else{
 return view('index.customer.customerabout');    
 }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `customers.customer_id` is a foreign key that references `users.id`, then:

- A customer can only have **one** user ("belongs to").
- But a user can have **many** customers ("has many").

So, inside `owners()` replace `belongsToMany()` with `belongsTo()`:

```
public function owners()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'customer_id');
}
```

And inside the `User` model, add a relationship to the `Customer` model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Customer', 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

Now you can check if a user has a given `package_id` in the `customers()` relationship:

```
Auth::user()->customers()->where('package_id', 1)->count();
```

Alternatively, you can use `isEmpty()` instead of `count()`.